Free open source tool to speed up video and store it that speed
Free open source tool to speed up video and store it that speed, i.e if I set it at 1.5x I should be able to save the video file in 1.5x.

A free multi-platform program known as Kdenlive will do as you require. The "store" reference should mean "save" and the output of the program will be in your selected format during the save process.
From the online manual:

Change speed will open the change speed dialog that will allow you to increase or decrease the playback speed of a clip, allow you to play the clip in reverse, and will enable / disable pitch compensation for the audio on a speed-adjusted clip.

These changes will be applied to the project and will be integrated into the exported/saved video.

One very simple software but powerful is Virtual Dub 2. One advantage is that potentially you do not need to recompress the video, but only store it with new values, in this case, framerate.
You need to define if you are multiplying the frame rate or if you are dropping frames. A video of 30FPS at 1.5x speed is 45FPS. You can easily change the frame rate or drop every 2 frames.
You probably need to resample the audio.
